# .htaccess - Permanently redirect to root when the website is accessed with mysite.com/index.php with no query string parameters?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am using a template on my website. This template is designed in a way where everything is in the `index.php` file but the functions are executed based on the query string which is stick to the `index.php` file.

I want to permanently redirect to the root `mysite.com` when my site is accessed with `index.php` with no query string parameters, but if there is any query string parameter then it should not be redirected and should remain the same.

To achieve this, this is what I added in my `.htaccess` file, but it affects the query string and the site is unable to be navigated properly.

```
...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The regex `^.*/index\.php` matches `index.php` followed by anything, which naturally includes the query string.

If it's always `index.php` in the document root then the above can be further simplified, since there is never going to be anything before `/index.php` in the URL-path.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\s
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Note the *space* (ie. `\s`) after `index.php` in the preceding *CondPattern*
to signify the end of the URL.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301 will have been cached.